# Как в react-router показать компонент только после полной его загрузки?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Как в react-router показать компонент только после полной его загрузки?
Т.е. после клика по Link url поменялся и начались подгружаться данные, но на экране все ещё предидущий компонент , только, после того, когда все данные загрузяться нужно показать актуальный

Comment: Это будет восприниматься пользователем как "ссылка не работает" - ведь после клика ничего не поменялось. Будут rage-кликать, пока компонент не отрисуется.

Comment: вверху страницы будет загрузчик как в инстаграм, вот в инстаграме и есть пример реализации того, что я хочу